# How to send app in background when back button is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to avoid the default behaviour of Flutter, instead of closing app when the back button (of the smartophone of course) is pressed I will send the app in background, so when I try to reopen the app it returns on the last screen.

I also tried a solution that I have found here, but didn't work.
This is the code:

```
 return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async =>
       await SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop'),
    child: Scaffold(
```

It also closes the app and don't send it in background.
The screen that contains the code showed above is the last route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MethodChannel` for this, invoke a method from Flutter that will trigger a method in Java.

```
// in flutter use something like this
methodChannel.invokeMethod("homeButton");
```

And in Java, you can create a method like:

```
public void homeButton() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

More info on how to [write platform specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Thank you a lot, you really saved me.

Comment: Always happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Flutter plugin for sending mobile applications to the background. Supports iOS and Android.

> move_to_background: ^1.0.2

```
WillPopScope(
  child: MaterialApp(...),
  onWillPop: () async {
    MoveToBackground.moveTaskToBack();
    return false;
  },
);
```